# Xamarin.Auth: Using Facebook oauth, how to redirect to my app?

Tags: facebook, oauth, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.auth

I've just started using Xamarin.Auth and I want to enable Facebook login via oauth.

Here is my config:

```
public static string ClientId = "client id";
public static string ClientSecret = "client secret";
public static string Scope = "email";
public static string AuthorizeUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
public static string RedirectUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
public static string AccessTokenUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/token";
```

Code for initiating the authentication:

```
public class AuthenticationPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
            Constants.ClientId,
            Constants.ClientSecret,
            Constants.Scope,
            new Uri (Constants.AuthorizeUrl),
            new Uri (Constants.RedirectUrl),
            new Uri (Constants.AccessTokenUrl)
        );

        auth.Completed += OnAuthenticationCompleted;
        PresentViewController (auth.GetUI (), true, null);
    }

    async void OnAuthenticationCompleted (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine ("AUTH Completed!");
        if (e.IsAuthenticated) {

        }
    }
}
```

Seems to work fine, but instead of redirecting the user to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html, I want to redirect him back to my app again. Any help much appreciated!

Best,
Sascha

Comment: why are you providing  https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as redirectionURL. redirectionURL should be your app url right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "redirect back" to your app again by simply invoking your own method to display the app's page you want to show to your user like this.

```
async void OnAuthenticationCompleted (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("AUTH Completed!");
    if (e.IsAuthenticated) {
        //invoke the method that display the app's page
        //that you want to present to user
        App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
    }
}
```

In your App.cs

```
public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
    {
        get
        {    
            return new Action(() =>
            {
                //show your app page
                var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
                masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MainPage)));
                masterDetailPage.IsPresented = false;                    
            });
        }
    }
```

Assuming that MainPage is the page you wanted to show after successful login. I am using Xamarin.Forms with MasterDetailPage to display pages in my example which maybe different from your app but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `DismissViewController (true, null)` in your `OnAuthenticationCompleted` method. Or use the async equivalent:

```cs
async void OnAuthenticationCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("AUTH Completed!");
    await DismissViewControllerAsync(true);
    if (e.IsAuthenticated)
    {

    }
}
```